# How to use an array from file A in file B

Tags: php, arrays, include

What is the right way to use an array from file A in file B?

When u use the example below, i get aan error (in Zend "Notice: Undefined variable: prefs") 
Then, if i var_dump $prefs, it shows me the correct array of type array.

Example:

**FILE A**

```
$prefs = array('test', 'anothertest');
```

**FILE B**

```
require_once('PATH_TO_FILE_A');
echo $prefs[0];
//output: test
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like this warning message, you can set a NULL $prefs **before** including file.

```
$prefs = '';
require_once('PATH_TO_FILE_A');
echo $prefs[0];
//output: test
```

Zend is warning you because actually $prefs isn't declared on file B .

P.S. : Really, you don't need this. Just ignore that warning message.

Comment: unfortunately this is no option to me. The array i use is an array with my language translations. The array i used in the example is just en example.

Comment: So, why you don't ignore this warning message ? It's not an error. I explained you, why you see this warning message.

Comment: I understand that, but as i use the translation in all parts of the website it will be crouded with errors :( (not nice to work with).

Besides that, somehow the content is not loaded too.

If i use the same array from the included file directly in my file, it works good.....

Comment: I got the solution, instead of using an array directly i returned the array from a class method.

Comment: @atjepatatje Errors != Warnings. Set error_reporting to only report errors and not warnings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if that's the right way to do that, then yes, it is. Your code should work as written.

When you `require` or `include` files into a PHP document, PHP treats them as if they were literally part of the master document. In your case, imagine copy and pasting the contents of File A into the top of File B. That's how PHP will treat it.